# Differential calculus question.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Find a constant c so that at any point of intersection of the two spheres $(x-c)^2+y^2+z^2=3$
and $x^2+(y-1)^2+z^2=1$ , the corresponding tangent planes are perpendicular to each other.

Comment: you need to compute  equation of tangent of  both sphere and consider  cases that perpendicular lines have  negative reciprocal slopes

Comment: this may help you http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225614/tangent-plane-to-sphere